# Solution is not showing in Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I created a project in Microsoft Team Explorer 1 week ago. Everything is working fine like check in new files, class etc. 2 days ago my Windows somehow corrupted. After installing Windows and VS, now solution is not showing in team explorer. Can't find local version also.

How can I get my solution which is present in Team Explorer to be shown?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "get latest" for the files to be local so that you can work on them.

Open "Source Control Explorer" find the root folder for your Solution, and right-click and select "Get Latest".